# Updating ImageView Bitmap inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Part of my application is using a ViewPager with three fragments as a "Wizard" for creating an event.  The first fragment features a default photograph in an ImageView and a button which launches an AlertDialog allowing the user to either take a new photo or use an existing photo to associate with the event.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Update Crawl Image" 
        android:onClick="fireImageDialog"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="284dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Once the user has selected the photo, I'd like for it to replace the default image.  The `fireImageDialog` recieves the path to the chosen image from either the `Intent.ACTION_PICK` OR `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` as expected, that is, I have confirmed that the path returned is a valid path to an image.  At the end of my `onActivityResult` method, I retrieve the Fragment containing the code above and call a method to set the bitmap of the `ImageView`.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == LOAD_CRAWL_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Some code here to handle the two potential sources of the path
                // sets `selectedImagePath`
                ((NewCrawlBasicDetailsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.newCrawlBasicDetails)).UpdateImage(selectedImagePath);
            } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

and the associated UpdateImage method:

```
public void UpdateImage(String path){
        if (path.length() > 0) {
            ImageView myPhoto = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            myPhoto.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(
                    path, myPhoto.getWidth(),
                    myPhoto.getHeight()));
        }
    }
```

My problem is that after all of this, the ImageView still shows the original default image.  I have tried to call `myPhoto.invalidate()` to force the view to re-draw, but haven't had any luck.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on?

Comment: Are you sure the decoding doesn't return null?

Comment: Yes, I've added a null check and confirmed via LogCat that the result is not null.